# Call variadic C function by its memory address in Delphi

Tags: delphi, typedef, variadic-functions, memory-address

Suppose I have a function in C++ in which I call it using a pointer to its memory address, with `typedef`. Now, how can I do the same thing in Delphi?

For example:

```
typedef void (*function_t)(char *format, ...);
function_t Function;
Function = (function_t)0x00477123;
```

And then, I can call it with: `Function("string", etc);`.

Is there any way to do this without using Assembly instructions, in Delphi?

Note that it is a variadic parameters function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An idiomatic translation for this:

```
typedef void (*function_t)(char *format, ...);
function_t Function;
Function = (function_t)0x00477123;
```

Is this:

```
type
  TFunction = procedure(Format: PAnsiChar) cdecl varargs;
var
  Function: TFunction;
// ...
  Function := TFunction($00477123);
```

The 'cdecl varargs' is required to get the C calling convention (where the caller pops the stack) and the variadic argument support (which is only supported with the C calling convention). Varargs is only supported as a means for calling C; there is no built-in support in Delphi for implementing variadic parameter lists in the C style. Instead, there is a different mechanism, used by the Format procedure and friends:

```
function Format(const Fmt: string; const Args: array of const): string;
```

But you can find out more about that elsewhere.

Comment: +1 for posting the real solution (getting the parameter types, cdecl and varargs right is more important than some people think).

Answer (score 2):

```
program Project1;

type
  TFoo = procedure(S: String);

var
  F: TFoo;
begin
  F := TFoo($00477123);
  F('string');
end.
```

Of course, if you just run the above you'll get a runtime error 216 at address $00477123.

Comment: This doesn't address calling convention or the variable number of arguments, so won't work correctly for his example.

Comment: David you're quite right. I wanted to illustrate function pointers, and hadn't noticed the varargs bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Delphi supports function pointers.  Declare it like this:

```
type MyProcType = procedure(value: string);
```

Then declare a variable of type MyProcType and assign the address of your procedure to it, and you can call it the same way you would in C.

If you want a pointer to a method of an object instead of a standalone procedure or function, add "**of object**" to the end of the function pointer declaration.

Comment: Thank you all, it worked.

But, there's a bug:

The function I'm trying to call, is similar to "printf".

In C++, when I call my function, with the string parameter as "string", it prints "string" in the console, but with Delphi, it prints "xÿ↕", I tried to change String to PChar, and so on, but no one worked. What can I do to print "string" correctly?

Comment: @Edward - apart from using the right parameter type you may also need to specify a calling convention. If you don't specify anything, Delphi will assume you want to use the "register" fastcall convention.

Comment: Try with PAnsiChar and check calling conversions.

Comment: PhiS, thank you to explain me of calling conventions. When a tried all calling conventions, none worked, but then, I saw pani's comment, and it worked perfectly, so thank you too pani!